# Using Ansible Vault Password Supplied From CLI in a Playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to use the ansible vault password supplied on the CLI in an playbook to create encrypted versions of a generated password.

```yaml
# generate_password.yml
---
- name: Generate and Encrypt Passwords
  hosts: "localhost"
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks: 
  - name: Generate Passwords
    set_fact: 
      encrypted_password: "{{ plaintext_password | ansible.builtin.vault(ansible_vault_password) }}"
    vars: 
      plaintext_password: "{{ lookup('community.general.random_words', min_length=5, numwords=4, delimiter='-', case='capitalize') }}"
```

The password needs to be passed to this filter `ansible.builtin.vault(ansible_vault_password)`

Currently, I've resorted to just using environment variables to collect the `ansible_vault_password` from the user or using the `vars_prompt` to gather it during playbook execution.

Is it possible to extract or reference that vault password when supplied via the CLI?

```bash
# can I access the vault password supplied via the CLI options

ansible-playbook generate_password.yml --ask-vault-pass

or `--vault-pass-file` option
```

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514072/how-to-automatically-pass-vault-password-when-running-ansible-playbook

Comment: @souser - that thread is about the various methods of supplying the ansible vault password file to the play. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to use the password AFTER it is provided. I'd like to use it to encrypt generated plaintext passwords as part of the playbook using the ansible.builtin.vault filter.